# Reset increment when counter reaches specific # after AJAX response in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I am having trouble with getting a counter to reset when it reaches a specific number.  I understand how to do this with a while-loop, but I can't seem to reset the counter properly and have the "loop" reset itself after a certain number of AJAX requests.

The full scope of my goal is to query a category of posts in wordpress via AJAX.  Each time a counter will increment which is then used as the value for 'offset' in the WP_Query(array()).  This portion I have working fine.  The trouble I am having is in having the offset variable reset back to 1 and start over... so as to create a loop of the posts.  I am not posting the portion that goes in functions.php because I don't believe I have any problems there, but if you think it will help, just ask and I will gladly add it.  See code below.

```
jQuery('#more_posts').click(nextTestimonial);
var page = 1; // What page we are on.
var ppp = 1; // Post per page
function nextTestimonial(){

    jQuery("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the

    jQuery.post(
        'http://localhost/kw/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        {
        'action': 'next_testimonial',
        'page': page,
        'ppp': ppp  
        }, 
        function(response){
            //page++; This works to increment fine if enabled
            if (page==3){ page = 1; } else {page++;} // <-- Trouble Here
            jQuery("#testimonial_box").html(response);
            jQuery("#more_posts").attr("disabled",false);
            jQuery('#more_posts').click(nextTestimonial);

        }
        );
 }
```

Comment: Why do dou have the 'page' variable inside the click function? Then you will start on page 1 again everytime you click it. Is this the desired behaviour?

Comment: It's not inside the click function, they are above the click function.  It may appear that they are inside, but the function is just below them.  The function is invoked via the jQuery statement above.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var page = 1; // What page we are on.
 var ppp = 1; // Post per page
```

The counter variables have to be outside your click function or it will not update. Or you have to have some sort of loop going on inside the function.

Comment: The counter variables are outside as I have commented above in response to Anokrize.  Plus, I moved them above the jQuery statement and it makes no difference.  I can get the counter to increment if I use the simple page++, but I am having trouble resetting it.